# \dfrac not converting to display style

Tags: latex, pdflatex

Coming back to LaTeX after a few years, I'm struggling to get `\dfrac` to do what it should. Specifically, indices on a summation don't go directly above/below the summation symbol unless I specifically convert to display style within both inputs to `\dfrac`.

Example code:

```latex
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\begin{document}
\[\dfrac{e^{\pi}}{\sum_a^b x}\] % no change to sum with \dfrac{\displaystyle e^{\pi}}{\sum_a^b x}
\end{document}
```

The sum in result is clearly not in display style:

[image]

To fix the sum index positions, I have to start the denominator argument with `\displaystyle`. Why would this be happening?
Environment: Running pdfLaTeX in Texworks, MikTeX. Not sure which version, installed in December 2021.

Comment: With `\displaystyle` the summation sign gets much too big and the fraction will look very unbalanced. I would use `\[\dfrac{e^{\pi}}{\sum\limits_a^b x}\]` instead

Comment: I think I'm fine with the sign getting large for my actual use case: a sum on both parts of the fraction, each with a multi-line substack.